# JavaScript universal way to know added new element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

`AddEventHandler` in JavaScript is for handling the events (like `onclick`) universally (i.e. on any element).

Is there a way to fire an event (don't know which kind) when a new element (i.e input, div, select, etc.) is being added to the page (through Ajax, jQuery, etc.)?

I've looked into the DOM documentation on dev Mozilla but couldn't find anything. May be I'm not looking in the right pages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is there a reason you want to know? If the reason is you want to add event handlers to new elements, you could use the "Live" functionality of jQuery instead.

Comment: Good to know about jQuery Live functionality. Thanks! Think if Google Analytics folks have to implement this functionality how they would pursue. Adding a new library (jQuery) won't be the case for them I think. Is there any other way that can be packaged with your existing js (without adding jQuery layer)?

Comment: Sure. Just read up on event delegation in JavaScript. http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/

Comment: @Rac123: But what if you don't want just to add events to it, but to actually do something with it? What if what one really needs is an... event fired on DOM changes? Is there a way?

Comment: Your answer is relevant only to this particular use case. It might have solve the issue for the original poster, but it doesn't answer the question in general.

Using `document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function (e) {})` for example is a more general solution.